# Spring Data JPA Receiving parameter value [2] did not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]

Tags: javascript, java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I know similar questions have been asked here already but believe me I did my research, tried lots of different approaches but no luck as of yet.

My configuration: Spring Data JPA (hibernate, H2 DB), a REST layer above and have an AngularJS client making requests.

REST path:

```
@RequestMapping("/search/{destinationId}/{arrivalId}/{departureTime}/{arrivalTime}/{numberOfPassengers}")
    public List<Flight> getFlightsWithCriteria(@PathVariable String destinationId,
                                               @PathVariable String arrivalId,
                                               @PathVariable String departureTime,
                                               @PathVariable String arrivalTime,
                                               @PathVariable Integer numberOfPassengers) { }
```

I'm calling the service as below:

```
/search/2/1/2016-08-15T21:00:00.000Z/2016-08-15T21:00:00.000Z/2
```

By the way, `departureTime` object is a `TIMESTAMP` on DB and test data is formatted as `2016-05-16 17:30:00.0`

Then parsing the date to be in a suitable format to match with DB:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date departureDate = sdf.parse(departureTime);
String formattedTime = dateFormat.format(departureDate);
```

Then using this formattedTime parameter in my query as follows:

```
flights = (List<Flight>) entityManager
                    .createQuery("SELECT f FROM Flight f WHERE f.departureTerminal = :destination AND f.arrivalTerminal = :arrival AND f.departureTime <= :departureDate AND f.numberOfSeatsAvailable <= :numberOfPassengers")
                    .setParameter("destination", destination)
                    .setParameter("arrival", arrival)
                    .setParameter("departureDate", newDate)
                    .setParameter("numberOfPassengers", numberOfPassengers).getResultList();
```

Then I of course receive:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2] did not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]
```

In the light of these, you might say why I'm sending `String` in query to a `TIMESTAMP` object, what I've tried so far:

- sent `String` in query,
- sent `Date` in query,
- sent `Date` in query with `TemporalType.TIMESTAMP`,
- used `@DateFormat` in `@PathParam`
- changed the whole entity model for date types to `String` and tried above again and again

..I've been scratching my head for hours on this but no solution yet.

Can you please take a look at my code and point me out what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to be clear with your groupings of the query operand by adding brackets where appropriate to help you with your logic and debugging, e.g. below

```
flights = (List<Flight>) entityManager
                    .createQuery("SELECT f FROM Flight f WHERE f.departureTerminal = :destination AND f.arrivalTerminal = :arrival AND (f.departureTime <= :departureDate)  AND (f.numberOfSeatsAvailable <= :numberOfPassengers)")
                    .setParameter("destination", destination)
                    .setParameter("arrival", arrival)
                    .setParameter("departureDate", newDate)
                    .setParameter("numberOfPassengers", numberOfPassengers).getResultList();
```

Just another thought, try passing 1 parameter then adapt your request to serve 1 parameter then proceed to 2nd parameter, and etc. That will pinpoint exactly which parameter is having problem.

Once you have discovered that culprit, now simplify your problem to just that parameter by passing as the only request parameter to fix it.

**UPADATE (My Solution):**

I had another crack at your code, and the query is fine. I suspect it is your input is the problem like the exception you reported. Here is what I did to test that is similar to your query if this helps you with your test.

**FlightTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestH2DatabaseConfiguration.class }, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class FlightTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FlightTest.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory")
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Test
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void test() throws ParseException {

        assertNotNull(entityManagerFactory);

        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        assertNotNull(entityManager);

        List<Flight> flights = (List<Flight>) entityManager.createQuery("FROM Flight").getResultList();

        assertEquals(2, flights.size());


        String departureTimeRequestInput = "2016-05-16T21:00:00.000Z";

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");        
        Date departureDate = sdf.parse(departureTimeRequestInput);
        Timestamp departureTimestamp = new Timestamp(departureDate.getTime());


        flights = (List<Flight>) entityManager.createQuery(
                  "SELECT f FROM Flight f "
                + "WHERE "
                + "f.destinationId = :destinationId "
                + "and "
                + "f.arrivalId = :arrivalId "
                + "and "
                + "f.departureTime <= :departureDate "
                + "and "
                + "f.numberOfPassengers <= :numberOfPassengers")
                .setParameter("destinationId", 1L)
                .setParameter("arrivalId", 3L)
                .setParameter("departureDate", departureTimestamp)          
                .setParameter("numberOfPassengers", 400L)
                 .getResultList();              

        assertEquals(1, flights.size());

        log.debug("**H2**SIZE: " + flights.size());     
    }

}
```

**TestH2DatabaseConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.mycompany.h2.jpa")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TestH2DatabaseConfiguration {

    final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestH2DatabaseConfiguration.class);

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("dataSource")
    public DataSource h2DataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).addScript("classpath:flight.sql").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        factoryBean.setDataSource(h2DataSource());
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.mycompany.h2.jpa");
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("flight_table");

        Properties ps = new Properties();
        ps.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        ps.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        ps.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(ps);       

        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();


        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return txManager;
    }   
}
```

**Flight.java**

```
public class Flight implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2608721697556397731L;

    @Id
    private Long destinationId;

    private Long arrivalId;
    private Timestamp departureTime;
    private Timestamp arrivalTime;
    private Long numberOfPassengers;
    ...
}
```

**flight.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE flight (
  destinationId      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  arrivalId          INTEGER,
  departureTime      TIMESTAMP,
  arrivalTime        TIMESTAMP,
  numberOfPassengers INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO flight VALUES (1, 3, '2016-05-16 17:30:00.0', '2016-05-18 17:30:00.0', 400);
INSERT INTO flight VALUES (2, 2, '2016-05-17 17:30:00.0', '2016-05-19 17:30:00.0', 200);
```

**Keypoint:**
The key point here is to past your user input time into java.sql.Timestamp object as shown in **FlightTest.java**, e.g.

```
        String departureTimeRequestInput = "2016-05-16T21:00:00.000Z";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");        
        Date departureDate = sdf.parse(departureTimeRequestInput);
        Timestamp departureTimestamp = new Timestamp(departureDate.getTime());
```

and

```
...
.setParameter("departureDate", departureTimestamp)
...
```

**Update2:** Sample Flight object insertion in transaction below

```
EntityManager entityManager = null;
try {
    entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
    transaction.begin();
    entityManager.persist(flightObject);
    entityManager.flush();
    transaction.commit();           
    return flightObject;
}
finally {
    entityManager.close();
}
```

Comment: I've just refactored the whole project (including unit tests of course) to switch Date type fields to Timestamp type. When I run the app and persisted some initial data, it worked ok and inserted everything as I expected (Mapped to TIMESTAMP in H2 DB). However I'm trying to query data with the sample code you've shared (sending Timestamp as the parameter) but no luck... I'm really out of options here, what can I do?

Comment: I think what you can do now is to list whether your inserted records are visible by doing a general query like entity id instead of timestamp then narrow the query result filtering with other criteria parameters. Finnally, filter with the timestamp. To ensure your entity is really inserted and its id is available, execute them in a transaction and flush.

Comment: Please check the above sample code what I meant by in transaction. Of course this is not the most ideal because it is not Spring managed transaction in a service class for testing this would be sufficient.

Comment: Just to let you know, if you want Spring to manage the transaction for you, you can follow the example in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38307395/jpa-left-join-without-onetomany-annotations link which I also answered there. The reason I am saying this is because I don't want to re-create those examples here.